# How to retain 0s after decimal point, after converting string to double

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str="-1.2300";
    double d = stod(str);
    cout<<d<<"\n";
}
```

output: -1.23

i am expecting output as following

-1.2300

Comment: ***i am expecting output as following*** That is really not how floats or doubles work.

Comment: Then you need to do formatted output with a precision specifier.

Answer (score 0):

If that is what you want, then you need to use formatted output with a precision specifier:

```
printf("%.4f\n", d);
```

or specify the precision for cout:

```
cout.precision(4);
cout << fixed << d << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, How can i do it with cout.

Comment: Added.  You will need to #include limits.h I think

Comment: Please lets not answer obvious duplicates.  Makes cleaning them up more difficult.

Comment: Didn't realize it was a dupe when I first answered.  I rarely answer C++ questions.

Comment: `cout` should be `std::cout`. And `<limits.h>` (or more accurately the C++ equivalent, `<climits>`, has nothing to do with this. You'll need `<iostream>` for `std::cout` and `<iomanip>` for `std::fixed`.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  That's why I rarely answer C++ questions.